# Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[xx.xx.xx.xx]: [13] Permission denied

Tags: permissions, agent

Currently I've about 30 Windows hosts with installed Zabbix Agents (template Windows by Zabbix Agent) on them.  But for some reason on 5 hosts I get above error. When I do nc -v -z  from Zabbix server I can establish connection without errors. What could be the cause of the problem?

OS on monitored hosts is Windows 10.
Zabbix agent 2 version 6.4.7
Hosts are behind NAT, but ports are redirected.
Firewall on host agents is disabled.